Assistance with Optimizing Batch Insert Query on SQL Server
I am inserting data into a destination table from a source table containing 13 million rows between two SQL Server databases.
Query 1: I use a full INSERT statement, which takes 40 minutes to complete:
INSERT INTO [Database_Dest].[dbo].[Table1_Dest]  
(  
    Column1,  
    Column2,  
    Column3  
)  
SELECT  
    Column1,  
    Column2,  
    Column3  
FROM [Database_Source].[dbo].[Table1_Source];  

Query 2: I attempted to split the process into smaller batches to make it faster:
DECLARE @batch INT = 100000;  
DECLARE @page INT = 0;  
DECLARE @lastCount INT = 1;  

WHILE @lastCount > 0  
BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

    INSERT INTO [Database_Dest].[dbo].[Table1_Dest]  
    (  
        Column1,  
        Column2,  
        Column3  
    )  
    SELECT  
        Column1,  
        Column2,  
        Column3  
    FROM  
        (  
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) AS RowNum, *  
            FROM [Database_Source].[dbo].[Table1_Source]  
        ) AS RowResult  
    WHERE RowNum >= (@page * @batch) AND RowNum < ((@page + 1) * @batch);  

    SET @lastCount = @@ROWCOUNT;  
    SET @page = @page + 1;  

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END;  

However, Query 2 takes even longer, completing in 70 minutes.
Can you please help me optimize Query 2 to reduce running time?
Thanks

Try WITH (TABLOCK) on both source and destination tables in the first query. Also no indexes on the destination table. There is no faster option than your first query, other than backup/restore.

You might not be able to optimize it, because you're hitting limits on your hardware etc. Direct insert can be helped by batches mostly only if you're running out of ram or temp space, otherwise not much to do except some smaller fixes that Charlieface mentioned. Run live plan on the query to see the parts that are taking time perhaps

I think, row_number() on 13 million rows, multiplied by page count - is expensive operation. You can take other possible key (for example Column1 ranges) for divide source table to batches.

@Charlieface, I added WITH (TABLOCK) to both the source and destination tables in the first query and removed all indexes on the destination table, but the running time remains the same at 39 minutes

Then you need to look at better disks, or maybe better network, because 13m rows should take max 5 minutes even on an old laptop. Also Standard/Enterprise/Developer editions are better than Express/LocalDB because it can parallelize.

@Charlieface, the source database is in an Azure VM (4 vCPUs, 16GB RAM) using SQL Server Standard edition, and the destination database is in Azure SQL Managed Instance (4 vCores, 5,1GB RAM/vCore). Both use Standard SSD disks

On which server are you running the query?

@Alex, on the destination database server Azure SQL Managed Instance

In your linked servers do you use distributed transactions (i.e. distributed transaction Coordinator)? Check collation settings of your linked server - they can have noticeable performance impact.
